# Sandboxing MSBuild

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

Is it possible to put `msbuild.exe` in a sandbox?

Long story short, Jenkins is used to deploy our assets. One of the things the deploy process issues is the following command from where the source was checked out from SVN:

`MSBuild.exe MsBuild.xml /t:Full /p:Configuration=Release /verbosity:minimal`

I would like to force `msbuild.exe` to start and stay in the folder where it was checked out. I'm hoping that I can simply pass a property to my generic command and that it cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the output path with `/p:DCC_ExeOutput="${WORKSPACE}\bin"`. This works also if you are using `$(OutputPath)` in post-build events.

So your call will become:

```
MSBuild.exe MsBuild.xml /t:Full /p:Configuration=Release /p:DCC_ExeOutput="${WORKSPACE}\bin" /verbosity:minimal
```

Edit: Specified the `Workspace`-folder `bin` as output dir.

The folder `bin` because I assume you use MsBuild to actually compile something.

Comment: @s-spieker Essentially, replace "C:\output\bin" with the folder where I checked out the source? I find the mention of "bin" to be confusing and relating to output of bin files?